# set UITextField as non editable - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

```
    [Number.editable = NO];
    [Number resignFirstResponder];
    [Password.editable = NO];
    [Password resignFirstResponder];
```

I am getting the error

Request for member 'editable' in something not a structure or union

:S

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Firstly, the `[...]` aren't needed if you're not sending a message.

```
Number.editable = NO;
[Number resignFirstResponder];
Password.editable = NO;
[Password resignFirstResponder];
```

But this is not the cause of error. [The `.editable` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/editable) is only defined for UITextView, not UITextField. You should set [the `.enabled` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) for a UITextField (note that a UITextField is a UIControl).

```
Number.enabled = NO;
...
```

Comment: i realised this and changed just after posting but that is still not working :S

Answer (score 18):

Also, you can use the delegate methods.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  return NO;
}
```

That would do the trick, I prefer this method over setting textField.enabled = YES when it's likely that the ability to edit will change during the lifecycle of the app.

Comment: The BlocksKit pod makes this even easier:

list.bk_shouldBeginEditingBlock = ^BOOL (UITextField *field) {
        return NO;
};

Answer (score 6):

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Note that this will mean that the user will not be able to do long press to copy also

Answer (score 0):

Returning NO from shouldChangeCharactersInRange would be better choice because if text is longer than the textfield width, then above solution will give problem, because user won't be able to see  all text(i.e. text hidden beyond the text field width)