# Property 'editable' not found on object of type 'UITextField *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Based from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275103/set-uitextfield-as-non-editable-objective-c), I can see that there's a property called *editable* exists on a UITextField. But when I tried to set it myself, I got the error `Property 'editable' not found on object of type 'UITextField *'`. What's wrong? Or is there another way to make UITextField not editable? Thanks.

```
UITextField *result = [[UITextField alloc] init];
result.editable = NO; // error here
```

Comment: @beyowulf I have, but unfortunately that's not what I actually looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Always look at the reference docs before posting a question like this.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, I was assuming that it exists according to the question and answer I referred to.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked clearly states that `editable` is a property of `UITextView`, not `UITextField`.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, ok, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
  textfield.enabled = false;
```

Or set the delegate of `textfield`

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ooh, so textField really does not editable property. Thanks for the alternatives.

Comment: FYI - it should be `textfield.enabled = NO;` or `return NO;`.

Answer (score 1):

For people programming in Swift with the same question,

```
    textfield.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Is a possible solution.

Comment: No, the equivalent would be `textfield.enabled = false`.